# Better way to search character in vector of vectors in scala

Tags: scala

I have a requirement where I have to search a character in vector of vectors. I have written a method which is very crude. What is a better way to search an element in vector of vectors.

Here is my code:

```
def search( xs: Vector[Vector[Char]], char: Char, rowIndex: Int): Pos = xs.headOption match {
  case None =>  Pos(-1, -1)
  case Some(row) => {
    val tuple = searchHelper(row, char, 0)
    if(tuple._1)
      Pos(rowIndex, tuple._2)
    else
      search(xs.tail, char, rowIndex +1)
  }
}

def searchHelper(xs: Vector[Char], char: Char, colIndex: Int): (Boolean, Int) = xs.headOption match {
  case None => (false, colIndex)
  case Some(col) =>
    if(col == char)
      (true, colIndex)
    else
      searchHelper(xs.tail, char, colIndex +1)
}

search(vector, c, 0)
```

Here is the input:

```
val input =
  """ooo-------
    |oSoooo----
    |ooooooooo-
    |-ooooooooo
    |-----ooToo
    |------ooo-""".stripMargin

val vector =
  Vector(input.split("\n").map(str => Vector(str: _*)): _*)

val c = 'S'
```

Comment: I recognize the Coursera assignment, so I'm not going to give a straight-ahead answer, but notice that you're looking for 2 different index values: the row index and the column index. The [Standard Library](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/Vector.html) offers a few different methods for extracting an index from a collection. Using 2 of those (as mentioned in the comment hints) the `findChar()` challenge can be solved with 2 lines of code.

Comment: Thanks.I just needed the hint.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this, perhaps?

```
xs
 .iterator
 .zipWithIndex
 .map { case (chars, idx) => (idx, chars.indexOf(c)) }
 .collectFirst {
    case (outer, inner) if(inner >= 0) => Pos(outer, inner)
 }.getOrElse(Pos(-1, 1))
```

To address a concern from the comments: this is *not* iterating through the entire list multiple times (not even once completely, as long as it finds a match earlier). Scala iterators are wonderful that way: you can write a chain of calls, that conceptually looks like a bunch of sequential transformations to the entire list, but is really executed lazily, element by element: the first element is is extracted from list, converted to a tuple `(chars, 0)`, fed to the `map`, then the result of that is sent to `collectFirst`, if the condition matches there, it stops and returns right away, otherwise, next element is taken from list, made into a tuple `(chars, 1)`, fed to the `.map`, etc ...

Comment: You are iterating over the complete outer vector (twice) + you are looking for the char in each inner vector. Then you are iterating again over the outer vector until you find your match. There was a reason why I did this with indexWhere and a mutable var ;) To reduce the amount of iterations.

Comment: Nope, I am not iterating over a complete vector. Not twice, not even once. That's what the `iterator` call is there for. Scala iterators are lazy. So, no, still no reason for mutable  state ;) Technically `.iterator`  isn't even necessary here (`zipWithIndex` already returns an iterator), I just out it there to make it obvious that all iterating is lazy.

Comment: Okay, my bad. Are you sure zipWithIndex is returning an iterator? Scala repl returns the whole vector indexed for me.

Comment: There you go ;) Thanks for pointing out that iterator is lazy.

Comment: Nope! Just checked it, and I was wrong, it returns the same type whatever it was called on. So, `.iterator` call _is_ necessary, and it needs to be _before_ `.zipWithIndex`. I fixed the answer.

Answer (score 2):

If, with better, you mean more concise, you could try leveraging the methods on Scalas collections:

```
def search( xs: Vector[Vector[Char]], c: Char ): (Int, Int) = {
    var innerIndex = -1
    val outerIndex = xs.indexWhere { inner =>
        innerIndex = inner.indexOf(c)
        innerIndex > -1
    }
    (outerIndex, innerIndex)
}
```

This assumes that you only need the first occurence of that character.

`indexWhere` terminates as soon as the innerIndex is larger than -1.

Maybe another possibility, which goes more in your recursive direction (and without a mutable var), but also with minimal iterations:

```
@tailrec
def search(xs: Vector[Vector[Char]], c: Char, n: Int = 0): (Int, Int) = {
  if (n > xs.size - 1) (-1, -1)
  else
    xs(n).indexOf(c) match {
      case -1 => search(xs, c, n + 1)
      case i => (n, i)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I will try to understand this code and create my own version.

Comment: ew, mutable vars!

Comment: @Dima 1. Feel free to suggest a better option to get the innerIndex out or provide another answer. 2. No state leaking out of the function, so I don't see the issue here.

Comment: @thwiegan yeah, I will :) State not leaking is a good thing, but in the end of the day, it never leaks beyond `main()` anyway ... So, the criteria should be not to write a function, that doesn't leak state, but to have a few places as possible that have it.

Comment: @kromastorm Added another possibility

Comment: @Dima You are right, but still I don't see an issue with that var in particular

Comment: I reversed my downvote (so now it is "up"), because you offer a recursive version. The "problem" with mutable state is largely the same as the problem with "leaking mutable state" - it makes the code less transparent and harder to reason about. We don't want it "leaked" not because "leaking" is bad, but because mutable state is bad, and we want it isolated and localize to as few places as possible, where it is really-really necessary. This is just not one of those places. If you are going to be writing scala code anyway, might as well do it idiomatically.

Comment: @Dima probably would've come up with a similar solution to yours, if I had thought about the laziness of iterators. Thanks for the insights :)

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way of doing it :

```
def findChar(c: Char, levelVector: Vector[Vector[Char]]): Pos = 
    val x = levelVector.indexWhere(_.contains(c))
    val y = levelVector(x).indexWhere(_ == c)
    Pos(x,y)
```

Indeed you have to assume there is only one correct answer.
Main idea :

1. First search for the row that have the character c
2. Then find the column in this row that has this character c